# Virtualbox change vhd type from immutable to normal

Tags: virtualbox

I have a virtual box with and immutable type storage which I need to change, so I'm trying to set the storage type back to 'normal' so I can persist my changes (before making it immutable again)

With the VM shutdown I run:

> VBoxManage modifyhd file.vhd settype normal

VBoxManage showhdinfo now correctly shows the type as normal, 
but changes are still not persisted after terminating the machine.

What could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

It is far easier to use the Built-in VirtualBox ***Media Manager***....

Make sure to update the VB when starting and before firing up any VM's Click **FILE** and then **MEDIA MANAGER**.

Select your appropriate VHD or whatever format disk you are using and choose the appropriate radio button, in this case it would be **NORMAL**

OK it and start the VM. You may have to start it from the VB Main Menu twice. Especially when switching back and forth from/to Immutable (Read Only) and Normal (Read/Write).

Hope that helps. Otherwise when using the CL you should use --Normal and --Immutable

Answer (score 1):

The missing step is to detach and reattach the disk.  Otherwise, the VM will keep on using the differencing image.

- In the Virtual Media Manager,

  - Right-click on the differencing image
  - ***Release...***
  - It also helps to delete (***Remove***) the differencing image.  Otherwise, VirtualBox will keep creating more, even after you're back to Normal.
- In your VM's ***Settings > Storage***

  - Add hard disk (Click square-plus icon at the top of the tree view)
  - Select the disk you previously changed back to Normal.